# Varnish 6 compatibility with RHEL 6

Tags: compatibility, varnish, rhel

Anyone knows if Varnish Cache 6 series are compatible with RHEL 6?

I'm particularly interested on the compatibility of Varnish LTS v6.0.4 and RHEL v6.10 (Santiago). I couldn't find any official documentation about this.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the reason. 
Looks like it's not compatible.

https://github.com/varnishcache/pkg-varnish-cache/issues/99

https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/whats-new/upgrading-6.0.html#packaging-changes